# Best way to efficiently manipulate lists within 3d array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I am given n number of lists within a 3d array. These lists represent time. So for example one of these lists may be (1,4) and this means 'busy' for 1:00, 2:00, 3:00, 4:00. So whats an efficient way of turning (1,4) into (1,2,3,4) for all n number of lists within a 3d array. Keep in mind n could be up to 10000. I'm probably being a moron here but thanks for help.

```
///requests is the array being given. eg [(1,4),(2,9),(4,5)]

numberOfRequests=len(requests)
mostTaxi=1
talArray=[]

//Very ineffiecient way of solving current problem    

for x in range(0,numberOfRequests):
    for y in range((requests[x][0]),(requests[x][1])+1):  
        talArray.append(y)

//


busiestTime=max(set(talArray), key = talArray.count)
mostTaxi=talArray.count(busiestTime)

return mostTaxi
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the tuples represent `(start, end)` time of a task, all You need to do is just get `end - start` from each tuple (it will represent the number of hours spend) and just get the max.

```
times = [
   [(1,4),(2,9),(4,5)],
   [(1,4),(1,20),(4,11)]
] 

def calculate_time(t):
  start, end = t
  return end - start

longest = max((max(map(calculate_time, each)) for each in times))
print("The longest task took", longest , "hours")
```